# Does static link import all symbols of static lib or just import those referenced symbols?

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

If a project referenced a libfoo.a, given that libfoo.a got some classes and some methods, the code actually used part of classes and methods, would the other completely unreferenced symbols go into final executable?

Furthermore, if added libbar.a into project, but the project didn't reference any symbols of libbar, would libbar.a go into final executable?

Comment: You can pass `--as-needed` to `ld`, which (I think) will make it *not* link to a library if no symbol is required from it.

Comment: I statically linked to d3dx9_43.a once and it wasn't used, none of the symbols or exports were added to my executable. Did not need `--as-needed`. I'd say it's just safer to listen to the guy above though rather than depending on the compiler.

Comment: the default behavior varies on different compilers, right?